# `--no-install-recommends` only specified packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to install xfce4-goodies but I don't want Midori Browser. With `--no-install-recommends` I don't know how to specify only Midori. I want the rest of packages. How to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you on?  `xfce4-goodies` doesn't pull in Midori on 16.04 (and I just ran a dry-run test with `apt-get install xfce4-goodies --dry-run` to see what it would install, and Midori isn't one of the things it installs)

Comment: Try `sudo apt install xfce4-goodies midori-` (assuming the Midori package is named `midori`).

Comment: @ThomasWard I read that here: https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/start But, you're right, it is not included...

Comment: @NETCreatorHosting-WebDesign That might just be the 'upstream' XFCE package for the goodies.  However, when actually checking what's installed or not, Midori isn't installed with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a confusion between the upstream XCFE.org pages which indicate Midori is one of the xfce4 goodies, and what is actually installed.

The actual dependencies of the `xfce4-goodies` package that it installs don't even reference Midori anywhere.  From `apt-get install --dry-run xfce4-goodies` on a standard Ubuntu 16.04 box:

```
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqmi-glib1 linux-headers-4.4.0-109 linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  exo-utils hddtemp libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libgarcon-1-0
  libgarcon-common libtagc0 libthunarx-2-0 libtumbler-1-0 libunique-1.0-0
  libvte-common libvte9 libwnck-common libwnck22 libxfce4ui-1-0
  libxfce4ui-common libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7
  libxfconf-0-2 lm-sensors mousepad ristretto thunar thunar-archive-plugin
  thunar-data thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common
  xfburn xfce4-artwork xfce4-battery-plugin xfce4-clipman xfce4-clipman-plugin
  xfce4-cpufreq-plugin xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-datetime-plugin xfce4-dict
  xfce4-diskperf-plugin xfce4-fsguard-plugin xfce4-genmon-plugin
  xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-mount-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes
  xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager
  xfce4-power-manager-data xfce4-power-manager-plugins xfce4-screenshooter
  xfce4-sensors-plugin xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin xfce4-systemload-plugin
  xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal xfce4-timer-plugin xfce4-verve-plugin
  xfce4-wavelan-plugin xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
  xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf
Suggested packages:
  ksensors devhelp fancontrol sensord read-edid i2c-tools
  tumbler-plugins-extra xfce4-cellmodem-plugin xfce4-linelight-plugin
  xfce4-messenger-plugin xfce4-mpc-plugin xfce4-radio-plugin xfswitch-plugin
  xfce4-hdaps gigolo parole xsensors
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  exo-utils hddtemp libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libgarcon-1-0
  libgarcon-common libtagc0 libthunarx-2-0 libtumbler-1-0 libunique-1.0-0
  libvte-common libvte9 libwnck-common libwnck22 libxfce4ui-1-0
  libxfce4ui-common libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7
  libxfconf-0-2 lm-sensors mousepad ristretto thunar thunar-archive-plugin
  thunar-data thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common
  xfburn xfce4-artwork xfce4-battery-plugin xfce4-clipman xfce4-clipman-plugin
  xfce4-cpufreq-plugin xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-datetime-plugin xfce4-dict
  xfce4-diskperf-plugin xfce4-fsguard-plugin xfce4-genmon-plugin xfce4-goodies
  xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-mount-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes
  xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager
  xfce4-power-manager-data xfce4-power-manager-plugins xfce4-screenshooter
  xfce4-sensors-plugin xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin xfce4-systemload-plugin
  xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal xfce4-timer-plugin xfce4-verve-plugin
  xfce4-wavelan-plugin xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
  xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf
0 upgraded, 67 newly installed, 0 to remove and 215 not upgraded.
Inst libxfce4util-common (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Inst libxfce4util7 (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfconf (4.12.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libxfconf-0-2 (4.12.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libxfce4ui-common (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Inst libxfce4ui-1-0 (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libgarcon-common (0.4.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Inst libgarcon-1-0 (0.4.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libexo-common (0.10.7-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Inst libexo-helpers (0.10.7-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libexo-1-0 (0.10.7-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst exo-utils (0.10.7-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libtagc0 (1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst thunar-data (1.6.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [all])
Inst libthunarx-2-0 (1.6.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [amd64])
Inst libtumbler-1-0 (0.1.31-2build2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libunique-1.0-0 (1.1.6-5 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libvte-common (1:0.28.2-5ubuntu3 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Inst libvte9 (1:0.28.2-5ubuntu3 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libwnck-common (1:2.30.7-5ubuntu1.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [all])
Inst libwnck22 (1:2.30.7-5ubuntu1.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [amd64])
Inst libxfce4util-bin (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst mousepad (0.4.0-3ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst thunar (1.6.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [amd64])
Inst thunar-archive-plugin (0.3.1-4 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst thunar-media-tags-plugin (0.2.1-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst thunar-volman (0.8.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst tumbler-common (0.1.31-2build2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Inst tumbler (0.1.31-2build2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfburn (0.5.4-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-artwork (0.1.1a~git+20110420-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Inst xfce4-panel (4.12.0-3ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-battery-plugin (1.0.5-4build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-clipman (2:1.2.6-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-clipman-plugin (2:1.2.6-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-cpufreq-plugin (1.1.2-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-cpugraph-plugin (1.0.5-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-datetime-plugin (0.6.2-2ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-dict (0.7.1-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-diskperf-plugin (2.5.5-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-fsguard-plugin (1.0.2-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-genmon-plugin (3.4.0-2build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-mailwatch-plugin (1.2.0-2ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-mount-plugin (0.6.7-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-netload-plugin (1.2.4-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-notes (1.8.1-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-notes-plugin (1.8.1-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-places-plugin (1.7.0-3 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-sensors-plugin (1.2.6-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin (0.4.6-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-systemload-plugin (1:1.1.2-0ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-timer-plugin (1.6.0-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-verve-plugin (1.1.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-wavelan-plugin (0.5.12-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-weather-plugin (0.8.9-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [amd64])
Inst xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin (1.5.1-1ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-xkb-plugin (1:0.7.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst ristretto (0.8.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-screenshooter (1.8.2-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-taskmanager (1.1.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-terminal (0.6.3-2ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-goodies (4.12.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-power-manager-data (1.4.4-4ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Inst xfce4-power-manager (1.4.4-4ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst xfce4-power-manager-plugins (1.4.4-4ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst hddtemp (0.3-beta15-52 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst lm-sensors (1:3.4.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libxfce4util-common (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Conf libxfce4util7 (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfconf (4.12.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libxfconf-0-2 (4.12.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libxfce4ui-common (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Conf libxfce4ui-1-0 (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libgarcon-common (0.4.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Conf libgarcon-1-0 (0.4.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libexo-common (0.10.7-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Conf libexo-helpers (0.10.7-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libexo-1-0 (0.10.7-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf exo-utils (0.10.7-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libtagc0 (1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf thunar-data (1.6.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [all])
Conf libthunarx-2-0 (1.6.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [amd64])
Conf libtumbler-1-0 (0.1.31-2build2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libunique-1.0-0 (1.1.6-5 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libvte-common (1:0.28.2-5ubuntu3 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Conf libvte9 (1:0.28.2-5ubuntu3 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libwnck-common (1:2.30.7-5ubuntu1.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [all])
Conf libwnck22 (1:2.30.7-5ubuntu1.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [amd64])
Conf libxfce4util-bin (4.12.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf mousepad (0.4.0-3ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf thunar (1.6.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [amd64])
Conf thunar-archive-plugin (0.3.1-4 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf thunar-media-tags-plugin (0.2.1-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf thunar-volman (0.8.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf tumbler-common (0.1.31-2build2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Conf tumbler (0.1.31-2build2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfburn (0.5.4-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-artwork (0.1.1a~git+20110420-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Conf xfce4-panel (4.12.0-3ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-battery-plugin (1.0.5-4build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-clipman (2:1.2.6-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-clipman-plugin (2:1.2.6-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-cpufreq-plugin (1.1.2-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-cpugraph-plugin (1.0.5-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-datetime-plugin (0.6.2-2ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-dict (0.7.1-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-diskperf-plugin (2.5.5-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-fsguard-plugin (1.0.2-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-genmon-plugin (3.4.0-2build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-mailwatch-plugin (1.2.0-2ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-mount-plugin (0.6.7-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-netload-plugin (1.2.4-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-notes (1.8.1-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-notes-plugin (1.8.1-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-places-plugin (1.7.0-3 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-sensors-plugin (1.2.6-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin (0.4.6-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-systemload-plugin (1:1.1.2-0ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-timer-plugin (1.6.0-1build1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-verve-plugin (1.1.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-wavelan-plugin (0.5.12-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-weather-plugin (0.8.9-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates [amd64])
Conf xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin (1.5.1-1ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-xkb-plugin (1:0.7.1-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf ristretto (0.8.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-screenshooter (1.8.2-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-taskmanager (1.1.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-terminal (0.6.3-2ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-goodies (4.12.1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-power-manager-data (1.4.4-4ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
Conf xfce4-power-manager (1.4.4-4ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf xfce4-power-manager-plugins (1.4.4-4ubuntu2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf hddtemp (0.3-beta15-52 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf lm-sensors (1:3.4.0-2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
```

Nowhere in this is Midori referenced.

Now, if you tried to install the full XFCE packagesets and not just the goodies package, Midori might be included.  (however it is not part of the standard packagesets anywhere, not even in the Xubuntu packagesets by default, unless it's pulled in as its own dependency)

Comment: Midori is unmaintained and unsupportable: see 
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864951

Comment: @DKBose yes, we know, this is why he doesn't want it installed.  We don't care if it's unmaintained and unsupportable, we only care if it's being pulled in as a dependency - which it isn't.  (OP wants to *exclude* Midori from being installed by anything from the `xfce4-goodies` package, but since it doesn't pull it in, it's irrelevant whether it's unmaintained or not)

Answer (score 5):

In this case, as Thomas has answered, `midori` is not one of the packages recommended by `xfce4-goodies`, so nothing special needs to be done.

However, in the general case, you can block specific recommended or suggested packages using [a hyphen after their name](https://askubuntu.com/a/880292/158442):

```
apt install xfce4-goodies xfce4-power-manager-
```

The `-` forces apt to consider the package for removal, so it won't be installed. Of course, this won't work for hard dependencies, only recommended/suggested packages, and for packages that are one of many candidates providing a hard dependency.

Correspondingly, when removing a package and its dependencies, you can keep a dependency by using a plus after it:

```
apt-get autoremove xfce4-goodies xfce4-artwork+
```

Any of the installation and removal subcommands of `apt` and `apt-get` can be used for both installation and removal thus.